# AngularJS: Cannot redirect inside resolve with failed $http Intercept

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

My AngularJS app has a $http intercept that checks for 401's returned from any api calls and redirects to the login state. This is working everywhere except on the following:

I have one state which has a resolve. Basically, before going to the User Details page, I want to load the user first:

```
.state('main.userdetails', {
url: 'users/{uid}',
templateUrl: 'views/user-details.html',
controller: 'UserDetailsCtrl',
controllerAs: 'ud',
resolve: {
    user: ['userService', '$stateParams', function(userService, $stateParams) {
        console.log('-- Resolver User called---' + $stateParams.uid)
        return userService.getOne($stateParams.uid);
    }]
}})
```

If I log in to the site, then delete my token from LocalStorage, when I browse to any $state that makes an API call, I'm redirected to the login page. However, when I browse to the above state, I see the User Details page with blank info. In the console, I can see that the interceptor was called but I am not redirected.

Inside userService.getOne():

```
userFactory.getOne = function(id) {
user = {};
return $http.get(config.apiURL() + '/users/' + id)
    .then(function(res) {
        user = res.data;
        return user;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Error GETing in userservice');
        return error;
    })};
```

And my interceptor's responseError:

```
responseError: function(rejection) {
if (rejection.status === 401) {
    console.log('--Auth Interceptor: responseError---');
    authToken.removeToken();
    $location.path('/login');
    console.log('---Auth Interceptor: sent to /login');
}
return $q.reject(rejection);}
```

The console shows me this:

```
--- Resolver User called---user1@test.com
GET http://test.com:3030/api/users/user1@test.com 401 (Unauthorized)
---Auth Interceptor: responseError---
---Auth Interceptor: sent to /login
Error GETing in userservice
---UserDetailsCtrl Entered---
```

Clearly everything's being executed in the right order, but the `$location.path('/login')` isn't doing anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I use $window.location.reload() when I get a 401 back. This gets into the MVC pipeline and verifies the user is authorized on the server.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I browse to the above state, I see the User Details page with blank info.

That's because your error handler

```
function(error) {
    console.log('Error GETing in userservice');
    return error;
}
```

returns `error`, which is in fact the rejection reason, that is, a plain string, and passes that string as the value of `user` to your controller. Since you're returning a valid string from your error handler, it assumes that the error was treated. To avoid this assumption, you can either, from the error handler, `throw` an error, or return a rejected promise (again).